# keyCode - Javascript

Tags: javascript-eventos

Boa noite meus caros,
estou fazendo uma 'function' em javascript porém não está executando em meu navegador Chrome.

```
  function move(){
         var obj = document.getElementById("dv1");
         var tecla = KeyboardEvent.keyCode;
         /*37 -Esquerda - 38-cima - 39-direita 40-baixo*/

         if(tecla==37){
            px-=10; //salto
            obj.style.left= px +"px";
         }else if(tecla==38){
            py-=10;
            obj.style.top= py+"px";
         }else if(tecla==39){
            px+=10;
            obj.style.left=px+"px";
         }else if(tecla==40){
            py+=10;
            obj.style.top=py+"px";
         }else if(tecla==13){
           alert("este evento foi para o beleleu");
           obj.removeEventListener("keydown",move); 
          }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown",move);
```

A ideia é trivial "deslocar um quadrado" com os "keydown", porém ao inspecionar no console do Chrome há um erro no "event.keyCode" que não consigo determinar.
Desde já agradeço a cooperação.

Comment: Mas você nem usou `event.keyCode` no seu código, como poderia dar erro nisso? E o que seria o `KeyboardEvent` em `var tecla = KeyboardEvent.keyCode`?

Comment: Boa noite Anderson, a transcrição foi errada. Mas o caso foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você cria uma função que é usada como *callback* de um evento, você deve estar atento aos argumentos que são passados para ela. Toda função que é executada em um evento, recebe como argumento um objeto do tipo `Event`, correspondente ao evento acionado.

Ao tentar pegar a tecla que foi "acionada", você está tentando fazê-lo no objeto *nativo* `KeyboardEvent`, ao invés de usar o próprio objeto `Event` que sempre é passado como argumento, como já mencionei.

Portanto, ao invés de usar o `KeyboardEvent`, defina um parâmetro (e.g. `event`) na função `move`, e obtenha a tecla pressionada. E ao invés de `keyCode` (que aliás está obsoleto), você pode usar o `which`, ficando assim:

```js
function move(event) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("dv1");
    var tecla = event.which;
    /*37 -Esquerda - 38-cima - 39-direita 40-baixo*/
    
    if(tecla==37){
        px-=10; //salto
        obj.style.left= px +"px";
    } else if (tecla==38) {
        py-=10;
        obj.style.top= py+"px";
    } else if (tecla==39) {
        px+=10;
        obj.style.left=px+"px";
    } else if (tecla==40) {
        py+=10;
        obj.style.top=py+"px";
    } else if (tecla==13) {
        alert("este evento foi para o beleleu");
        obj.removeEventListener("keydown", move); 
    }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", move);
```

> **Nota (28/05/2020)**: hoje, tanto o `keyCode` como o `which` estão obsoletos. De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Obsolete_properties), a propriedade mais apropriada pra ser usada no lugar é a [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), o que deixaria o código dessa forma:
>
> ```js
> function move(event) {
>    var obj = document.getElementById("dv1");
>    var tecla = event.key;
>    
>    if(tecla == "ArrowLeft"){
>        px-=10; //salto
>        obj.style.left= px +"px";
>    } else if (tecla == "ArrowUp") {
>        py-=10;
>        obj.style.top= py+"px";
>    } else if (tecla == "ArrowRight") {
>        px+=10;
>        obj.style.left=px+"px";
>    } else if (tecla == "ArrowDown") {
>        py+=10;
>        obj.style.top=py+"px";
>    } else if (tecla == "Enter") {
>        alert("este evento foi para o beleleu");
>        obj.removeEventListener("keydown", move); 
>    }
> }
> document.addEventListener("keydown", move);
> ```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Opa!!! Obrigado Gustavo ajudou, acabei não passando o parâmetro "event", o "KeyboardEvent" foi um erro de transcrição, testei algumas possibilidades da MDN antes de postas no stack. Mas deu certo com o "which", aliais não o conhecia. Vou dar uma pesquisa mais profunda no "which".